# Cannot install Groovy-Eclipse on STS

Tags: spring-tool-suite

It shows that groovy-eclipse has been installed, however I cannot find any groovy related options in creating new file wizard.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I see the same in both 3.5.x and 3.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading/installing Groovy and Grails from this update site.
You should be able to see in the log why Groovy plugins failed to start. Perhaps they were unresolved due to something missing from the installation. The most likely cause is JDT Java 8 patch for Groovy hasn't been installed. Therefore, ensure all Groovy features selected when installing Groovy from the update site above.